# Creating quarterly rasters from monthly rasters for multiple years with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator

I'm attempting to create quarterly rasters from monthly PRISM .bil files that I've already masked to my ROI. Essentially I'm trying to automate the process of using Raster Calculator to add 3 monthly rasters together (Jan + Feb + Mar = Q1) because I have 11 years of monthly rasters to combine into quarters.

I've already tried using an iterator in ModelBuilder, but I couldn't do what I need. I'm hoping this is possible using Python code though. My monthly rasters are organized into separate subfolders for each year with names like "07_0" for Jan 2007, "07_1" for Feb 2007, etc.

[image]

Is there python code that could iterate through each yearly subfolder and add each successive group of 3 rasters together into quarterly raters?

Here's my code so far:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env


arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# creat a variable for the folder with rasters
workspace = r'F:\Water Balance\Data\GIS_data\Rainfall\PRISM\Masked_rasters\2007'

# create a variable for output folder
ws_out = r'F:\Water Balance\Data\GIS_data\Rainfall\PRISM\Qtr_rasters'

# Set the environment workspace to the workspace folder
env.workspace = workspace
env.OverwriteOutput = True
# get a list of grids from the workspace
rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
# for loop to set groups of 3 rasters at quarters
for raster in rasterList:
    jan = rasterList[0]
    feb = rasterList[1]
    mar = rasterList[2]
    apr = rasterList[3]
    may = rasterList[4]
    jun = rasterList[5]
    jul = rasterList[6]
    aug = rasterList[7]
    sep = rasterList[8]
    oct = rasterList[9]
    nov = rasterList[10]
    dec = rasterList[11]

# use raster calculator sum the rasters in each quarter and make a new 
raster
from arcpy.sa import *

# Use map algebra to add month raster into quarters
outRas = Raster(jan) + Raster(feb) + Raster(mar)
outRas.save("F:\Water Balance\Data\GIS_data\raster_test\2007_q1")
```

Comment: For help with code please include a code attempt.